# Video.JS: How do I add my own custom play and pause button in the middle of the video-container?

Tags: jquery, html, css

For an assigment I need to make a site with a dark-mode, pop up modal, an accordion with multiple videos inside of them and the video players needs 3 custom buttons. To play, pause and to "check" that you finished the tutorial, which pops up the modal.

How can I add my  buttons on the video-player and in the center? I cannot seem to get the  button (green button) correctly inside the video.js player itself. I thought that making the the video `position: relative` and the button `position absolute` would do the trick, but it still goes over the whole site instead of contained in the video itself

```css
#my-player {
    position: relative;
}


.video-button {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    
}

#video-play {
    background-color: green;
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <h4> 
     <span> <i class="fas fa-caret-right rotate arrow"></i> Algemene       introductie </span>             
   </h4>
                            
   <div>
     <video id='my-player' class="video-js" controls data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
       <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogv">
       <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm">
     </video>
   <a class="video-button" id="video-play">></a>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.4/video.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Position Absolute and Relative correctly, you have to place the element with '''position:absolute''' inside the '''position:relative''' element.

Something like this should place the button within the video element:

```
<div id='my-player' class="video-wrapper">
  <video  class="video-js" controls data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogv">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
  <a class="video-button" id="video-play">></a>
</div>
```